# Проблема с выборкой из базы

Tags: mysql, while, php, get

Здравствуйте! Прошу помочь, мучаюсь с этим уже 2 дня, все перепробовал. У меня один шаблон, переход по ссылкам идет методом GET, меняется только блок контент. Вот в head название сайта title сделал проверку для каждой ссылки, все работает, для каждой ссылки идет свое название, но вот когда перехожу на новость по id методом get название для всех новостей пишет название первой новости, то есть если тема называется, например = 2, 3, 4, и 5 то выводится 1. Думаю проблема в цикле, пробовал while тогда сайт вообще не открывается. Вот код для проверки. Помогите, как решить эту проблему.

```
<head>

<title>

    <?
        if (empty($_GET)) {echo'Академия';}

        elseif ('index.php' == $_GET['categories']) {echo'Академия';}

        elseif ('news.php' == $_GET['categories']) {echo'Новости';}

        elseif ('read.php&id='.$rownewsall['id']) {echo      $rownewsall['name_news'];}

        elseif ('sotrudniki.php' == $_GET['categories']) {echo'Сотрудники';}

    ?>

</title>

</head>
```

вот сам код для проверки названия по id

```
elseif ('read.php&id='.$rownewsall['id']) {echo      $rownewsall['name_news'];}
```

и вот сама страница с новостями, обратите на название при переходе на новости, их там 2 всего

http://greenplanet.mackay.kz/?categories=news.php

Как проверить, чтобы выводило название новости. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не много желающих отвечать. )) Я не исключение, однако, не хочется оставлять вас совсем без ответа. Попробую хоть как-то направить вас в нужном направлении. Итак, как я вижу, все GET-запросы идут в index.php. Вот и ладненько. Если использовать обычный вид ссылок (**param_name = param_val**), то **param_name** можно описывать, ключевым словом, которое будет обозначать определенный раздел. Например, **article** для статей, **employee** для сотрудников, **page** для страниц. А **param_val** id записи в соответствующей разделу таблице. В итоге, ссылки могли бы выглядеть следующим образом:

```
http://greenplanet.mackay.kz/?article=2
http://greenplanet.mackay.kz/?article=5
http://greenplanet.mackay.kz/?page=2
http://greenplanet.mackay.kz/?employee=1
```

Теперь переходим к обработчику:

```
// проверяем, пуста ли каждая из возможных переменных
if(!empty($_GET['article'])) $article = (int)$_GET['article'];
if(!empty($_GET['page'])) $page = (int)$_GET['page'];
if(!empty($_GET['employee'])) $employee = (int)$_GET['employee'];

// собственно, теперь мы можем узнать, из какой таблицы нужно делать выборку
// и какую именно запись достать
if(isset($article) && $article){
   // запрос на выборку из таблицы со статьями
}
if(isset($employee) && $employee){
   // запрос на выборку из таблицы сотрудников
}
if(isset($page) && $page){
   // запрос на выборку из таблицы страниц
}
```

При том, что примерчик примитивный, он вполне рабочий. Кроме того, советую подумать об использовании [ЧПУ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3_%28%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%29). Если не сразу, то пусть это будет следующим шагом на тяжком пути веб-разработчика ))

Comment: спасибо, долго не отвечали, но за это время, я решил проблему, точнее нашел ошибку, надо было названия взять в цикл и там же опять сделать проверку сравнить с get id и все заработало, вот в общем код 

   elseif($_GET['read.php&id='].$rownewsall['id'] == $rownewsall['id']){
 
while($rownewsall  = mysql_fetch_array($rnews)){

   if($_GET['read.php&id='].$rownewsall['id'] ==
 
$_GET['id']){

   echo $rownewsall['name_news'];
   }
   }
            }